# Command line program don't work correct on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

Command line program don't work correct.

I write test.py and setup.py, and do "python setup.py install".

I run "test.py", it results editer open test.py.

test.py don't print "test".

My enviroment is Python 2.7.6 on windows.

Please advise.

setup.py

```
# coding: UTF-8

from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name = "test",
    version = "0.1",
    scripts = ['test.py']
)
```

test.py

```
# coding: UTF-8
print u"test"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

I delete editer, and it appear "select which program starts" window when I run test.py.
I select python.exe on this window.

Answer (score 1):

your `test.py` has to start with `#!python` so the setup tool can use it.

from the documentation:

> Scripts are files containing Python source code, intended to be
>   started from the command line. Scripts don’t require Distutils to do
>   anything very complicated. The only clever feature is that if the
>   first line of the script starts with #! and contains the word
>   “python”, the Distutils will adjust the first line to refer to the
>   current interpreter location.

Comment: @hucuhy maybe the problem is that your python executable is not set correctly. see here: http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts

Comment: I read it and I run their command, but I doesn't work correct.